# How to decipher SNMP packets?

Tags: snmp

How to decipher `SNMP` (request, response, trap) packets that are captured through `SPAN` port.

What is the standard format of `SNMP` packet so that I can traverse through the packet to extract information using C program.

I found some information from [here](https://www.ranecommercial.com/legacy/note161.html) but the information is very old.

Comment: If you check IETF RFC documents on SNMP http://www.snmp.com/protocol/snmp_rfcs.shtml, then most of them are pretty old as SNMP is not a new protocol. Not surprised as similar protocols are very old too.

Answer (score 0):

For SNMP, nothing much has changed in all those years. The information for SNMP vs 2 should still be valid.

The definitive answer if of course in the RFCs. For SNMP vs. 2:

- RFC 1901. Introduction to Community-based SNMPv2
- RFC 1908. Coexistence between Version 1 and Version 2 of the Internet-standard Network Management Framework
- RFC 3416. Version 2 of SNMP Protocol Operations
- RFC 3417. Transport Mappings

And for SNMP vs. 3:

- RFC 3410. Introduction and Applicability Statements for Internet Standard Management Framework
- RFC 3411. An Architecture for Describing SNMP Management Frameworks
- RFC 3412. Message Processing and Dispatching
- RFC 3413. SNMP Applications
- RFC 3414. User-based Security Model
- RFC 3415. View-based Access Control Model
- RFC 3416. Version 2 of SNMP Protocol Operations
- RFC 3417. Transport Mappings
- RFC 3584. Coexistence between Version 1, Version 2, and Version 3 of the Internet-standard Network Management Framework
- RFC 3826. The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Cipher Algorithm in the SNMP User-based Security Model
- RFC 5343. Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Context EngineID Discovery